# Pros/cons of shifting perspective on topology and considering $\tau$ on its own without $X$.

Tags: general-topology

What are the pros/cons of "shifting perspective" in topology and considering only $\tau$, without considering $X$ at all, or, equivalently with $X$ being tacitly taken to be $\cup\tau$?

---

One possible advantage that I can think of is that we can treat *literally any* set as a subbase of a topology. This means we can add a function symbol $t$ that closes a subbase under arbitrary unions and finite intersections.

Comment: What is your question? Your notion of "semitopology on $X$" just looks like a topology on a subset of $X$. There is a notion of [topology without points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointless_topology) that you may find more interesting.

Comment: @RobArthan That's true. It is a topology on a subset of $X$. I'm curious what the pros and cons are of talking about topologies on their own with the topological space in question being implied/[not meaningful].

Comment: Well write up a specific question about that!

Comment: @RobArthan Sorry, I thought the first question was narrow enough. I changed it  to remove the extraneous material.

Comment: There be such a category  thing as pointless topology.  The disadvantage is that  the topos category can only handle sober spaces.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [Kuratowski closure operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_closure_axioms) is what you are looking for. If you prefer, you could use the dual notion of [interior operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_(topology)#Interior_operator).